# sftp download without keyring prompt - without change of .bashrc

Tags: linux, bash, sftp

For a bash install script, I need to download files with sftp. When doing so, a gnome keyring prompt will open. This can be avoided by some changes in .bashrc or so.

But as my script should run on any machine without changing settings there, I'd need a solution which avoids that keyring lookup. Can somebody help?

Comment: Have you consider using ssh keys (with ssh agent)?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but space is limited in the comments section and may put you on the right path.

> This can be avoided by some changes in .bashrc

This is worrying.

1. You assert this is possible but you don't provide any details of what the changes are nor why you think this is the case
2. If the behaviour can changed in .bashrc then it should be just as easy to change the behaviour inside your script

You didn't tell us what sftp client you are using. This is certainly not the default behaviour of Openssh sftp (you did not say what you are using) but its possible that when you type 'sftp' at the command line something else is happening before handing off to the actual sftp client. You might want to check the output of `which sftp` and `alias sftp`.

Again, assuming that this is openssh, then the behaviour maybe implemented via the SSH_ASK_PASS shell variable (start a terminal emulator and `echo $SSH_ASK_PASS` to check). If that is the case then you simply need to set the variable to blank within your shell script.

It is also possible that the keyring is activate as a helper program by the ssh_config. If that's the case then the config will be somewhere in /etc/ssh/ssh_config or a file included in that depending on which distribution of Linux you are running (you did not say). This config can be overridden on the sftp command line in your script.

Comment: Sorry for being so little precise. Now:

Comment: it's open ssh from ubuntu 22;  
'echo $SSH_ASK_PASS' gives a blank;  
'alias sftp' results in 'bash: alias: sftp: not found';  
'which sftp' produces '/usr/bin/sftp'       
  
"This config can be overridden on the sftp command line in your script." - That's what I'm seeking for. Thank you for your help.